# Receive POST request from Swift in Node.js

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, http, post

I am trying to receive and process a POST request being sent from my iOS app to my Node.js web server. The server responds with HTTP Error 502 whenever I try to send this POST request. Could you please look at my code below and see what is wrong with it? Thank you!

**Node.js Code**

```
app.post('/applogin', function(req, res) {
   var parsedBody = JSON.parse(req.body);
   console.log(parsedBody)
});
```

**Swift Code (POST function)**

```
func httpPost(jsonData: Data) {
    if !jsonData.isEmpty {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        URLSession.shared.getAllTasks { (openTasks: [URLSessionTask]) in
            NSLog("open tasks: \(openTasks)")
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (responseData: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            NSLog("\(response)")
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    }
```

**Swift Code (sending of the POST request)**

```
@IBAction func onClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let username = Username.text
    let password = Password.text

    var dataString = "username: \(username), password: \(password)"

    let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)

 httpPost(jsonData: data!)

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have correct route path set in node.js? You have `app.post('/applogin'` probably It shoul be `app.post('/app/login'`. On what addres you try post request from your swift code?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak it is /applogin!

Comment: Is request received using postman?

Comment: No. How do I recieve using postman? @Lazyexpert

Comment: Try to reach your nodejs API endpoint using postman: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop. Than you know where the problem is.

Comment: Your nodejs server isn' sending back a response.

Comment: I ran it using Postman. Now it says: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: do you use body-parser middleware?

Comment: I am not using HTML. I am using Swift and iOS

Comment: But yes, I do have the body-parser middleware @Lazyexpert

Comment: Show how you plug it in.

Comment: @Lazyexpert here you go: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Is it used before router is plugged in?

Comment: @Lazyexpert I am not using a router object. I am just using the 'app' variable, aka 'var app = express()'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149447/discussion-between-lazyexpert-and-safal-r-aryal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send a json instead dataString, and you have to set the "Content Type" header with value "application/json"

**Swift 2**

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestUrl)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let params = ["username" : username, "password" : password] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

 request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options:NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Answer (score 1):

Many answers they don't mention that we need to set header for the request from Swift side before sending to the backend otherwise it'll be a string in a wrong format that we can't use `JSON.parse`, here's what I firgured out (NOTE the IMPORTANT line):

```swift
let json = [
            "email": emailTextField.text
        ]

        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

        let url = URL(string: BASE_URL + "/auth/register")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // insert json data to the request
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        //IMPORTANT
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                print(responseJSON)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

And in your NodeJS with Express just call `req.body` and you're done

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.post('/applogin', function(req, res) {
   var parsedBody = JSON.parse(req.body);
   console.log(parsedBody)
   res.send("Request received")
});
```

Comment: It still says the same error, Unexpected Token o at JSON position 1

Comment: It would have been nice if you had posted that error along with the question.